# Create a new ArrayList in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist

I'm new to programming in `Netbeans`, so keep it as simple as possible, please.

So, right now I have 3 java files in the same project: mainframe.java, edit.java and add.java.

In the mainframe-window you have 2 buttons which get you to the edit and add-window. In the add-window you get to enter a text in a text field and then press a button to add it into an `ArrayList`, I did this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    List<String> Hey = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

And the Button:

```
private void btnFortsattActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 

{ 
    //The variable name of the text field is "txfCreate"

    String text = txfCreate.getText();
    Hey.add(text);  //The problem here is that Netbeans cannot find "Hey" symbol 

}
```

Next, in the edit-window, I have a `JList` to show the content of the `ArrayList`. I have no idea know how to code it:(

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Variable Scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)

Comment: there's nothing related to netbeans in this question. Like doing the same thing in eclipse would work...

Comment: Try to read about Variables Scopes in Java. You will find an aswer in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class My {

List<String> Hey;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Hey = new ArrayList<String>();
}

private void btnFortsattActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    //The variable name of the text field is "txfCreate"

    String text = txfCreate.getText();
    Hey.add(text);  //The problem here is that Netbeans cannot find "Hey" symbol 
}
```

}